# passportjs req.isAuthenticated() always returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server, passport.js

I am using react for my frontend and its hosted on port 3001, while my backend is hosted on port 3000. I am sending a GET request to the server from my frontend to a route that runs "req.isAuthenticated()" and then returns "true" if the client is authenticated or "false" if it's not, the problem is, as the title suggests, that it always returns "false" no matter what. When logging in i console.log the req.user after authentication and it successfully prints the user, thats not the case with the check-authentication route, it prints "undefined", even though the cookie is sent with the request, well.. a cookie named "connect.sid" atleast, which I bet is the one.

## My login route:

```
req.login(user, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/signin");
    } else {
      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function () {
        req.session.save((err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);
          } else {
            console.log(req.user);
            res.redirect("http://localhost:3001/");
          }
        });
      });
    }
  });
});
```

## My check-auth route:

```
app.get("/api/check-auth", (req, res) => {
  console.log("Session:", req.session);
  console.log("User:", req.user);

  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    // User is authenticated
    console.log("true");
    res.json({ authenticated: true, user: req.user });
  } else {
    console.log("false");
    // User is not authenticated
    res.json({ authenticated: false });
  }
});
```

## General stuff/setup:

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
  cors({
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
    origin: "http://localhost:3001",
    credentials: true,
  })
);

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "This is a secret key.",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: MongoStore.create({
      mongoUrl:
        "myClusterUrl"
    }),
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: true, //when false throws error "needs to be secure in order to be "none" samesite"      
      sameSite: "None",
      domain: "localhost:3001",
    },
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

mongoose.connect(
  "myClusterUrl"
);

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: String,
  password: String,
  email: String,
  cart: [productSchema],
  reviews: Array,
});

userSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);

passport.use(User.createStrategy());

passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());
```

## My frontend:

```
const [authenticated, setAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const checkAuth = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:3000/api/check-auth",
          { withCredentials: true }
        );
        console.log(response.data); //always prints "authenticated: false"
        setAuthenticated(response.data.authenticated);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error checking authentication status:", error);
      }
    };

    checkAuth();
  }, []);
```

At first I had set my frontend using form, and I am pretty sure I had the same issue, no errors just returning false, and I saw on a forum that a guy used "fetch" to make the request so it can also send the cookies with it, so I went ahead and changed my request from "form" to "axios" and added "withCredentials: true" for the cookies, which lead to other errors with the request/response headers
which I tried to solve inside CORS configurations & res.headers, using the help of google, but they didn't really do much, the error was still there, sometimes changing between an "origin cant be *" *(even tho I had specified it) or some allow-access-something doesnt include X (which was included), so someone recommended me to add a "proxy" on my frontend and that fixed this error.

After that I thought maybe its a serialize/deserialize issue so the session is not saved correctly and tried doing this insead of the above

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function (err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

but it still returned false.

Then copilot suggested I should use another way to authenticate the user cause this was "creating a new user instead", and suggested I should use bcrypt to compare the passwords, but that was returning an error.

Also tried app.use(cookieParser()) as suggested from another post, nothing really changed.

Tried adding "http://" on "domain" under the cookies configuration

I think I have tried pretty much everything suggested by google/copilot/chatgpt but nothing fixed my problem.Any ideas?

Comment: It could be an issue with your session storage, I'm not very familiar with mongoose unfortunately though, have you used npm to install the proper controller for express session to use? I think it is also likely to be an issue with your deserizlization having some error where the query for the full user returns undefined. If I'm not wrong in your final example you have serialized the user not the user.id, then you use id instead of user.id in your findById call, so your actually passing the full user into that call. I believe you also need to handle success by calling done(null, result) too.